# Is there any workaround for GLIBCXX_3.4.20 and 3.4.21 in CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos7

I'm running CentOS 7...  I know officially they are never updating their GLIB but I need something that's not 5 years old.

I tried installing a package that has them but it's not working... It says I need all these other dependencies which don't seem to exist.  https://altlinux.pkgs.org/sisyphus/classic-x86_64/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm.html

Is there a stable work around for this?  It appears that it's been a problem for years now. Hopefully one of the old CentOS gurus has figured out something.

```
[rdavis@hopper temp]$ sudo yum localinstall libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, remove-with-leaves
Examining libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
Marking libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libstdc++.i686 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * epel: sjc.edge.kernel.org
 * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * updates: mirror.hostduplex.com
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15) for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) for package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) for package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
---> Package libstdc++6.x86_64 0:8.2.1-alt1 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-core >= 6:2.3.6-alt7 for package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: .sisyphus.214000.20.1.1-libgcc1-8.2.1-alt1 for package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.18)(64bit) for package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: rtld(GNU_UNIQUE) for package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.18)(64bit)
Error: Package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++ = 4.8.5-36.el7
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++ = 4.8.2-16.el7
               libstdc++ = 4.8.5-36.el7
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               libstdc++ = 8.2.1
Error: Package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-36.el7
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-36.el7
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
           Requires: rtld(GNU_UNIQUE)
Error: Package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Removing: libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 (@base)
               libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)
           Obsoleted By: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
           Requires: .sisyphus.214000.20.1.1-libgcc1-8.2.1-alt1
Error: Package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 (/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64)
           Requires: glibc-core >= 6:2.3.6-alt7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[rdavis@hopper temp]$ sudo yum localinstall libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm --skip-broken
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, remove-with-leaves
Examining libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
Marking libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libstdc++.i686 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * epel: sjc.edge.kernel.org
 * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * updates: mirror.hostduplex.com
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15) for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) for package: 1:qt-devel-4.8.7-2.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) for package: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) for package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.i686
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
---> Package libstdc++6.x86_64 0:8.2.1-alt1 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-core >= 6:2.3.6-alt7 for package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: .sisyphus.214000.20.1.1-libgcc1-8.2.1-alt1 for package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.18)(64bit) for package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: rtld(GNU_UNIQUE) for package: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64 from /libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt1.x86_64
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?
I'm getting similar errors when trying to install MySQL;